# Run Python Script in VM (Ubuntu) via Cron Job

Tags: linux, google-cloud-platform, cron, virtual-machine

I have a problem where I want to run (daily at 2pm) a Python code in my VM but the cronjob didn't work as expected.

Here is the code that i tried in `crontab -e`:

```
#1    
0 14 * * * /home/try/myf.py
#2
0 14 * * * /home/try/miniconda3/bin/python /home/try/myf.py
#3
0 14 * * * python /home/try/myf.py
#4
0 14 * * * /home/try/miniconda3/bin/python myf.py
```

All of this code didn't work for me. Can anyone explain or advice me on how to do the code? If possible, how can I check the log of this cronjob?

Comment: did you try "which python"?

Comment: yes i am. this is the output /home/try/miniconda3/bin/python

Comment: what's your user on server? are you root?

Comment: how can i know im a root or not? can u explain.... please...

Comment: if you are logged in on server, your user name should be user@your-server-ip in case of non root user otherwise it should be root@your-server-ip. DON'T PASTE YOUR IP HERE

Comment: if you are not root then check if that user is allowed to run cron because i can't see anything wrong with #2 in your attempts. So mostly there is something wrong with the user permissions. And if you want to keep logs of your cron then it's recommended to create a bash file(.sh) where you write your logging logic and log the output in some log file.

Comment: i see.. so im root in this server. so any material that i can follow for enable that permission? @VPC

Answer (score 1):

Checklist:

1. Check cron daemon running ?
   (`ps aux | grep cron`) or `service cron status`
   `Service cron start` or `restart`
2. check if cron is working ?
   `contab -e` and add below line

   - - - - - ( /bin/date && /etc/echo "cronjob works" ) >> /tmp/file

   Then `cat /tmp/file`

There are other posts explaining checks and tests in detail, refer those

Answer (score 0):

#2 is correct, it works with miniconda3 on ubuntu instance.
Replace the code in myf.py with `print('hello world')` and try running  ​
`/home/try/miniconda3/bin/python /home/try/myf.py` manually.
If it works, then it's a crontab issue.
There's a great troubleshooting guide [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/449651/why-is-my-crontab-not-working-and-how-can-i-troubleshoot-it).
If it doesn't work, then your miniconda installation is corrupted. Try reinstalling it following [these instructions](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/install/linux.html#uninstalling-anaconda-or-miniconda). Remember to close the terminal and re-open it after the installation, otherwise it won't work even if the installation has been successful.